# Stretching Banner, and Centering the Footer

Tags: html, css, footer, banner

I'm trying to vertically stretch my vertical side banners to the bottom of the page, and make the footer in the bottom left be in the bottom center. I've been looking for a solution to this issue, but am unable to find it as of yet. I am doing this for a school assignment, and thus, am still in the learning process. Please explain what needs to be done to fix this too if you can. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Play - Learn - Grow</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body class="body">

        <span class="headers_t">

            <span class="banner_h">
                <img src="Images\Top_Banner_4.png" alt="Banner" height="150" width ="1240" />
            </span>

            <nav>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="membership.html">Become a Member</a></li>
                    <li><a href="borrow.html">Borrow Toys</a></li>
                    <li><a href="policies.html">Our Policies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sitemap.html">Site Map</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </span>

        <span class="banner_l">
            <img src="Images\Side_Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" />
        </span>

        <span class="banner_r">
            <img src="Images\Side_Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" />
        </span>

        <h2 class="headers">Welcome to the Home Page!</h2>

        <div class="container">

            Our aim is to provide the children of the community with an ever-changing variety of educational and fun toys to enhance
            their cognitive, social, emotional and physical development in the important first six years of their lives.

            <br><br><span class="Links">Be sure to check out our Wikispace site with more information <a href="http://mysocialmediatools-pn.wikispaces.com/">here</a>!</span>

        </div>

        <div id="content"></div>

        <div id="footer">
            Copyright &copy 2013
        </div>


      </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Entire Document CSS */
html{
    height: 100%;
}
/* Header CSS */
.headers_t{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.headers{
    color: #FFD89A;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* Body CSS */
.body{
    background-color: #61B329;
    height: 50%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 191px;
}
.container{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 50em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    height: 50%;
}
/* Navigation CSS */
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #00B2EE;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 14.28%;
    float: left;
}
.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Banner / Picture CSS */
.banner_l{
    float: left;
}
.banner_r{
    float: right;
}
.banner_h, img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
/* Footer CSS */
#footer {
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 3em;
 margin-top: -3em;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}
/* Link CSS */
a:link{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    background-color: #028482;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active{
    background-color: #FCDC3B;
    color: #AA00FF;
    text-decoration: overline;
}
.Links A:hover{
    color: #028482;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline overline;
}
```

This is what the problem in the site looks like:

[Image of Problem http://i.tinyuploads.com/cwPP9R.jpg](http://i.tinyuploads.com/cwPP9R.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jokan welcome! Its typical for front end questions like this to be mocked up on a site like jsfiddle.com, that way other users can easily see what your talking about and help you find a solution.

If I understood you correctly, heres your solution in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4RTt/1/). You just want the banner to be the height of the browser window right?

I just set the height of `.banner_h` to 100% like so:

```
.banner_h {height:100%;}
#footer {width:100%; text-align: center;}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, but I think you meant that for .banner_l and .banner_r. That worked like a treat, but what about the footer positioning? Any way that can be in the bottom of the page, centered?

I will upload a JFiddle next time, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Jokan Definitely, sorry I missed that part of your question.  I updated my answer with footer centering and here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/H4RTt/2/.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, ammend your following css style to-

```
.banner_l{
    float: left;
    border:thin solid #000; 
    width:200px;  
    position:fixed; 
    height:auto; 
    min-height:380px; 
    margin-top:-20px;
}
.banner_r{
    float: right;
    border:thin solid #000;
    margin-top:-20px; 
    width:200px; 
    min-height:380px; 
    height:auto; 
}

#footer {
width:100%;
height:30px; 
background:#090; 
float:left; 
position:fixed;
padding:5px; 
bottom:0px; 
text-align:center; 
}
```

change position style to relative or absolute as u need.

Comment: Ahh the background footer feature is pretty good, thanks for that!

Comment: Lemme know if u need any help, I appreciate your contribution towards school.